# How do I get dimensions on product page? (not as product specification) - nopCommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

I want to show the dimensions uploaded from the layout on product page, because I have a lot of products and every SKU has different dimensions, so I'll be wasting a lot of time adding every measure as product specification.

I've found an extension for the version 1.9, but I'm working on 3.0.

Comment: I think you might want to ask this question at the NopCommerce community as well(http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/f/6/development.aspx), they can give you the answer faster, but I think you will have to create a plugin for it, since NopCommerce isn't going to add this in 3.2 as seen on roadmap: http://www.nopcommerce.com/roadmap.aspx

Comment: already did, they got nothing I have to code :)

Comment: ah wait I saw your question on the nop forum:), I think i can help you out a bit, I did also add custom fields for my nopcommerce shop, and I have some experience in showing the values on the front-end, tell me where you are stuck.

Answer (score 3):

1. Add these properties to the Models\Catalog\ ProductDetailsModel:

   ```
   public decimal Weight { get; set; }
   public decimal Length { get; set; }
   public decimal Width { get; set; }
   public decimal Height { get; set; }
   ```
2. Assign values ​​to these parameters in the PrepareProductDetailsPageModel method of the CatalogController. To do this you should find the string "var model = new ProductDetailsModel()" and after "IsCurrentCustomerRegistered = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.IsRegistered()," add the following lines:

   ```
   Weight = product.Weight,
   Length = product.Length,
   Width = product.Width,
   Height = product.Height
   ```
3. Add the new properties to the ProductTemplate.Simple.cshtml and ProductTemplate.Grouped.cshtml views:

   ```
   <div>
      <span class="label">Weight:</span>
      <span class="value">@Model.Weight</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span class="label">Width:</span>
      <span class="value">@Model.Width</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span class="label">Length:</span>
      <span class="value">@Model.Length</span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span class="label">Height:</span>
      <span class="value">@Model.Height</span>
   </div>
   ```

for example, after "@Html.Partial("_SKU_Man_Stock", Model)" line.